# Template.QuerySelector inside Template Tag Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, templates, lwc

I am trying to render a jsonTree instead of just json text and have the following javascript code to do it (Note: It is in a switch statement):

```
                case 'LONGTEXT':
                this.isLongText = true;
                var wrapper = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="tree_destination"]');
                var treedata = JSON.parse(this.value);
                var tree = jsonTree.create(treedata, wrapper);
                
                break;
```

Here is the HTML:

```
     <template if:true={isLongText}>
            <div data-id="tree_destination">This is my tree.</div>
        </template>
```

I am quite new to all of this, so sorry if there is a trivial mistake. The library I am trying to use to get the tree can be found at this link: https://github.com/summerstyle/jsonTreeViewer
or https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-tree-viewer

The error I am getting is "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null" and I am getting it on the `jsonTree.create()` line. I am almost 100% sure that it has to do with the wrapper, but I am not completely sure. When I do console.log of the wrapper, though, it returns null.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: Could you tell us in which situation you call the javascript part ? The error message itself basically says that `this.template.querySelector` returns `undefined`. This can be because you run the code too early (DOM is not yet ready/inserted) or the query doesn't work (LWC is a bit special at time). Aside from that, including 3rd party lib in LWC can be hard as they have something called "Locker Service" which prevent modification of the DOM outside of the component scope and library are not always compliant with this.

Comment: You probably need to use `lwc:dom="manual"` [directive](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library) as well.

Answer (score 2):

[`template` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) aren't standard elements. To access their contents, you use the [`content` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTemplateElement/content), which is a `DocumentFragment`. So change your `querySelector` to:

```
var wrapper = this.template.content.querySelector('[data-id="tree_destination"]');
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^
```

```js
const template = document.querySelector("template");
const div = template.content.querySelector('[data-id="tree_destination"]');
console.log(div);
```

```html
<template if:true={isLongText}>
    <div data-id="tree_destination">This is my tree.</div>
</template>
```

Note that I can't guarantee that particular library is happen to render into a disconnected element, but this does solve the `querySelector` problem. :-)

Comment: Hi - thanks so much for the response! Do you know if this applies to the Lightning Web Components template tag? I don't think I made that clear in the question, but this is specific to LWC.

Comment: @Alex88 - `template` is a standard HTML tag/element. I haven't used LWC so can't comment on that, but it would be Very Weird Indeed if they made `template` not a `template`. :-)

Comment: There is no such `content` property in LWC. For the record, here is the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_dom_work) of the querySelector in LWC.